# Remove or Encode Non-UTF-8 Characters in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```perl
use Encode;
$str = "good\x{c3}\x{82}\x{c2}\x{92}";

my $data= decode('utf8', $str);
```

Desired output:

```
good
```

what we can do to remove non utf characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-utf8"?  Can you add your desired output?  (And why does the title say "or Encode"?)

Comment: Maybe `s/[^[:ascii:]]+//g` will do?

Comment: desired o/p :-  compilations arent a genre

Comment: See https://ideone.com/7Bl3f5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It will, but written that way seems slower to read and type than the equivalent `s/\P{ascii}+//g` would be, don't you think? :) Although it may enjoy amortized cross-tool cognitive advantages for some folks, IMHO the awkwardness of the `[^[:ascii:]]` syntax needed for [negated complements of POSIX-y character classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Negation-of-POSIX-character-classes), with its careful bracket-doubling and inversion and circumcolons, derives less from being 3 punctuation characters longer than `\P{ascii}` than from increased mental-processing costs.

Answer (score 2):

`g`, `o` and `d` are all part of UTF-8's character set, Unicode. Yet you didn't remove them in your desired output. So your request to remove non-UTF-8 aka non-Unicode characters is incorrect.

You actually appear to be asking to remove non-ASCII characters. This is achieved using the following:

```perl
my $data = decode( 'UTF-8', $bytes ) =~ s/[^\x00-\x7F]+//gr;
```

Because of properties of UTF-8, you could also use the following which might be quicker:

```perl
my $data = decode( 'UTF-8', $bytes =~ s/[^\x00-\x7F]+//gr );
```

---

Note that `utf8` is a Perl-specific extension of UTF-8 used internally by Perl. The correct encoding to use is `UTF-8`. (The names are case-insensitive.) This is reflected above.